# Is Oracle unique key constraint case sensitive?

Tags: oracle, unique-key

I am planning to switch my database from mysql to oracle. So I just wanted to know this?
So that I can make changes accordingly

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I thought MySql is case sensitive?

Comment: The question is really not about "unique key." The question is, in comparing character string expressions, is Oracle case sensitive? Whether it is or not will control many things (including what is considered a "duplicate" in things like unique key constraints). You already got the answer, it's YES. I am saying all this because you may have to make many changes if you need to make one. If you were coming from a case insensitive DB, you might have to change many of your queries, etc., not just a few constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Oracle is case-sensitive.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id VARCHAR2(20) PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO test ( id ) VALUES ( 'TEST' );
INSERT INTO test ( id ) VALUES ( 'test' );
INSERT INTO test ( id ) VALUES ( 'Test' );
INSERT INTO test ( id ) VALUES ( 'TesT' );

COMMIT;

SELECT * FROM test;
```

**Outputs**:

```
ID                 
--------------------
TEST                 
TesT                 
Test                 
test
```